# Is doing drush archive-dump enough to transfer a drupal site to another server?

Tags: drupal, drush

I am relatively new to Drupal. I have a drupal site on my staging but I would like to transfer the site to production server. My question is: Is doing drush archive-dump enough to do this? I tried doing this and it seems like the site is not loading the configurations correctly? I already executed the sql commands from the file generated by the dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three components to moving a Drupal site to another server:

- Database
- Code
- Files (e.g. files uploaded by content creators; usually `sites/all/public`)

drush archive-dump is specifically there to grab all three and tar them. So yes, that is all the data you need. There can be other issues (e.g. server permissions; software versions; DB credentials; etc...)

Answer (score 1):

To go live you need to:

1. Test your site in the same environment as production site have.
2. Move code to production server.
3. Move database to production server.

That's all.

Please read:

- http://www.slideshare.net/erikwebb/the-basics-of-smart-drupal-deployment
- https://www.drupal.org/best-practices

Answer (score 0):

Almost. It seems that archive-dump will not include the Private Files Directory if it resides outside the DocumentRoot.

Some administrators will place the Private Files in a directory such as DOCROOT/sites/default/files/private/ and although Apache 2.x should deny access to this directory directly via .htaccess rules, placing this outside the DocumentRoot entirely ensures that protection regardless of HTTPD service...

So no, archive-dump is coming up short if you have Private Files outside your DocumentRoot directory.